# Bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I can't make bootstrap dropdown to work. 
Here is my html for nav:

```
<ul class='nav'>
  <li class='active'>Home</li>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href='#'>Personal asset loans</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">asds</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Payday loans</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And here are the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Check my answer at similar posting 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592158/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-any-browser/23486239#23486239

Comment: My issue was missing the bootstrap js file, in case that helps someone else

Comment: I had updated my ```Gruntfile.js``` which changes some of the paths in the ```jsFileList```...Updating the paths and running the appropriate Grunt tasks (grunt dev / grunt build / etc) solved my problem.

Comment: @Drewdavid Thanks! I was missing `bootstrap.min.js` *and* `jquery`

Comment: In newer versions of bootstrap you need to include bootstrap.bundle.min.js, which includes popper.js and important! use "data-bs-toglle" instead of "data-toggle"

Comment: Same this happens 8 years later on Bootstrap 5.1 :)

Comment: Presently using Bootstrap 5.1 and ran into the same issue.  I found that I added both `bootstrap.bundle.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` (for some unknown reason).  After removing `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` my dropdowns worked.

Comment: @Jens, there's a typo in your comment. It should be "data-bs-toggle"

Comment: Check the top four answers. I actually needed all four to make it work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Working demo: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp73

try this

```
<ul class='nav'>
  <li class='active'>Home</li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Personal asset loans</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">            
        <li><a href="#">asds</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>   
    </li>
    <li>Payday loans</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The dropdown in your demo no longer seems to work, or perhaps the problem is with my browser.

Answer (score 193):

I had the same problem. After a couple of hours of trouble shooting found that,

I had

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

instead of,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Imray, the bootstrap script registers extensions to jQuery, so if jQUery isn't loaded, the extensions are never registered.

Comment: Thanks. Worked also for my angular 10 project in angular.json file

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned that if you use the latest CDN's for Bootstraps CSS & Javascript that you don't need the second script in the original question (the one with ".dropdown()". If you just follow the installation guide for the latest bootstrap version it should work fine. At time of writing this can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 115):

I had the same problem when I included the `bootstrap.min.js` twice. Removed one of them and it began working.

Comment: This fixed my issue. My angular app was pulling in multiple copies of bootstrap through the gulp task to inject my bower_components

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks

Comment: this fixed it in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with bundles

Comment: Fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: really annoying... using aurelia-webpack-skeleton I need to import bootstrap.css in my main.js, but if I import 'bootstrap', I get that weird behavior...

Comment: I am using AdminLTE(having bootstrap) in Rails application and included all JS twice -- wasted almost 2 hours. Thanks removed one and it worked all at once

Comment: Does anyone know why this is an issue?

Comment: Amazing how common this is LOL. Tried to figure this out for hours only to realize I have bootstrap called in the header and footer of my doc. Eish.

Comment: it saved me a lot of time

Comment: Worked for me as well. Excellent !

Answer (score 89):

In bootstrap 5, need to change from `data-toggle='dropdown'` to `data-bs-toggle='dropdown'`

Comment: Yeah this one is the only one that worked for me, even took the example straight from bootstraps docs and it didn't work, but now I noticed that I was looking at docs from v4

Comment: Just did the exact same. Copied from the documentation... but needed to change the code as above. I wish they would leave things the same.. makes it impossible to upgrade to new versions!

Comment: This is the one that did it for me! I was so confused, I knew I was importing the bootstrap bundle and jquery correctly, and I used the example code directly from the docs.  So glad I found your message!

Answer (score 26):

FYI: If you have bootstrap.js, you should *not* add bootstrap-dropdown.js.

I'm unsure of the result with bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: Thanks. I had both the dropdown.js and bootstrap.js and thus it didn't work. Removing the dropdown.js solved the problem.

Comment: You are the best man, I spent around 6 hours on this to find where is the issue!!, thanks again..

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! I have the same problem, but I have `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js.`. When I removed the latter, it works.

Comment: Thanks - In my case, I had both `js/bootstrap.js` as well as `js/dropdown.js`

Answer (score 15):

I just added `JS` part of `bootstrap` to my index page, then it worked

**Paste this, if you're using the latest version of bootstrap (01.12.2020)**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Yes, I know. But there are other people who may face this problem

Comment: What was the latest version of bootstrap at the time of this answer ?

Comment: @tama I'm not sure what was the latest version at that time. But it seems like I used here the version 4.5.3

Comment: Adding .bundle in bootstrap JS link fixed the issue for me, thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much brother... Only this awenser is actually works for me....

Answer (score 14):

For your style you need to include the css files of bootstrap, generally just before `</head>` element

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Next you'll need to include the js files, it's recommended to include them at the end of the document, generally before the `</body>` so pages load faster.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>        
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Add following lines within the body tags.

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files 
        as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some time.

Answer (score 7):

you have to import this files into the `<head></head>` of your html.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have no idea why or what I was doing incorrectly, but this answer did it for me. Thanks Martin!

Comment: Thank you.  I do not know why this has solved the problem either. The menu worked fine with /js/jquery.js and /js/bootstrap.min.js until the website was migrated to another Windows server.

Answer (score 6):

Have you included  `jquery.js` ?

Also, compare this line of code with yours:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Personal asset loans<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

See this version that works ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap dropdown</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">w3resource</a>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <h1>Dropdown Example</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Both bootstrap and jquery must be included:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/{ProjectName}/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/{ProjectName}/js/jquery-x.x.x.custom.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="/{ProjectName}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/{ProjectName}/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

NOTE: jquery-x.x.x.min.js version **must be version 2.x.x** !!!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out and the simplest way to do this ist just copy and past the CDN of bootstrap link that can be found in https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ and the Jquery CDN Scripts that can be found here https://code.jquery.com/ and after you copy the links, the bootstrap links paste on the head of HTML and the Jquery Script paste in body of HTML like the example below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>

        <title>Purrfect Match Landing Page</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="griddemo.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>

      <body>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>    
      </body>
    </html>
```

For me works perfect hope it works also for you :)

Comment: Thank you ! , moving it before the `</body>` tags got it working on my end !

Answer (score 3):

Here what i did is .....

Just removed bootstrap.min.js from my Project and added bootstrap.js to it and it started working........

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
                  //"~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));
```

Comment: Adding to #kubilay Answer : you can have a single class named 'A' per document. .min.css/.min.js - are generally the same css and js files with all spaces removed from them. It makes them smaller and load faster. Browser won't need spaces anyway.

Comment: Remove one if you have Used both

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Bootstrap</h1>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing a dropdown menu problem, maybe this help you to get out of it

Step 1:
[BootStrap Download Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/)

Step 2:
Jump over to this *"CDN via jsDelivr"*Copy and Paste CDN into the Web-Head tag

or

Otherwise, just copy the code below and paste it into the head tag, and good to go.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To Improve the speed of the website, add a script tag before the closing body tag.

I hope this would help you.
Regards,
Ahmad Iqbal Bhatti

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the head section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy-paste below jQuery `<script>` and stylesheet `<link>` into your `<head>` to make sure you're loading all necessary files.

> It's important that your JQuery `.js` file is above `.css` stylesheet

**Simply paste the following line to test**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

> The problem occurs mostly with loading of jQuery script, make sure you
>   add references correctly.

**Now test**

Still if it doesn't work, check bootstrap website they've a sample implementation.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#supported-content

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check conflicting css files/properties for example you could have ".nav" custom style contents elsewhere try to disable your own css files and check if that works then check which file or custom style that makes the conflicts
also make sure you are including the bootstrap.min.js in your code

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue only to observe that i had added the bootstrap script **twice** and the second bootstrap script was after **above** the jquery script.

Solution:

- Ensure that bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js are only included once in your file.
- The bootstrap.min.js script should be included after jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

For latest Bootstrap you will need **Popper.js**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Copy the link in the End of the Body section just before the `<body>` Tag, inside `<Head>` Tag.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the original question turned out to be the answer. On [bootstraps documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) there is no mention of using a script to enable dropdowns but it appears to be necessary for it to function, at least in my case.

Once I added this script from the original question it magically started working.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>
```

--Edit: The root cause was something to do with the formatting of my parent nav container, I blew away my entire nav section and replaced it with bootstraps example and it started working without the script. So either solution works but blowing it away seemed to be the "correct" way for me as the script felt like a cheat.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was using bootstrap v3.1.1 which doesn't include styling for `.dropdown-item` despite having styling for `.dropdown-menu`. Bootstrap 5 has both.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved in my case once I added the bootstrap.bundle.min.js instead of bootstrap.min.js. Appears that popper.js and other needed js are packaged in bundle.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which brought me here.

My Issue : I was using the recommended jquery 1.12.0 version as my jquery script file.

Solution : replaced the jquery script with jquery 2.2.0 version.

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a CORS issue. I removed `crossorigin="anonymous"` from my script importing tags, and it started working again.

BTW the latest script tags, in the correct order, can always be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/

Edit: Apparently adding `defer` to the `script` tag will also break all the Bootstrap goodies.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste the CSS link followed by the JS link from the bootstrap site [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/). Then the dropdown should work.

My page looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Website Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" />
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Navbar from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/))

Answer (score 0):

Check popper.js library because I had same problem, you can find bootstrap, jquery and popper CDNs for drop down on https://getbootstrap.com/
or jus copy the following script tags

Answer (score 0):

My (same) problem arose when I mixed up the css and the bootstrap versions.
I was using version 3 bootstrap.min.js with version 4.5 bootstrap.min.css

If you've loaded or overwrote a bunch of css and js files to your static folder recently, it would be a good place to start.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using Angular 12 and Bootstrap 5. My problem was that I had mistakenly put a CSS file into the scripts section:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
          "node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          "node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss"  <===== in wrong section
        ]
```

The app built OK and ran with no errors shown in the browser console, but the dropdown toggle did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone is struggling with this problem in `angular`. Then here is a quick way to fix this issue.

Don't need to install `popper` or `jquery` vis `npm`, simply paste below lines in your `index.html` file inside `head tag`

```
  <!-- BootStrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper --> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- BootStrap JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Full working code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Some Website</title>
  <base href="./"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!-- BootStrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper --> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <!-- BootStrap JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 30 minutes reading up on this problem. My Dropdown would not open. Tried several approaches and nothing. Until... VERSIONS! Not all Bootstrap versions work with Laravel. Only the latest version of Bootstrap would work with the latest version of Laravel. No matter if the difference is minor modifications. You have got to make sure of that first.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I import the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` in npm and `index.tsx` file, I have already imported `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` then install the bootstrap using npm. remove the `index.tsx` script block import:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

works.

Answer (score -3):

I had setup with Angular 7, jQuery 3.4.1, Popper 1.12.9 and Bootstrap 4.3.1, nothing was working for me unitll I did this little hack in styles:

```
.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Html looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top py-1">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="dropdown-id"
                aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-id">
                <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]='["/"]'>Main page</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]='["/about"]'>About</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]='["/about/terms"]'>Terms</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]='["/about/privacy"]'>Privacy</a>
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```