# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown not working in any browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to do a dropdown menu and it seems to work in Jsfiddle. It seems that the javascript and css files are correctly loaded:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Lti.jpg

But it doesn't work in any of my browsers. I have tested it in Firefox 19.0.2, Google Chrome 25.0.1364.172 and Internet Explorer 9.0.2. Javascript is enabled and running.

Javascript is included before Bootstrap and bootstrap-dropdown.js is the only bootstrap file I have included, I mean that I have not included bootstrap.js.

There is nothing in my error console.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding-top: 60px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
              }
              .sidebar-nav {
                padding: 9px 0;
              }
        </style>
        <link href="./css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">  
            <div class="container">  
                <ul class="nav">  
                    <a class="brand" href="#">w3resource</a>  
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
                    <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu">  
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>  
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                            <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>  
                            <li class="divider"></li>  
                            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>  
                        </ul>  
                    </li>  
                </ul>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            <li class="nav-header">Componentes</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.well -->
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="span9">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span4">
                             <h2>Canvas</h2>
                             <canvas id="myCanvas">Tu explorador no soporta canvas.</canvas>
                            <script>

                            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                            ctx.fillStyle="#AA0000";
                            ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

                            </script>

                        </div>
                        <!--/span-->
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/.fluid-container-->

    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>© Company 2013</p>
            </footer>
        <script src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The Dropdown menu of the section Tutorials, works fine for me... but i'm loading the bootstrap for another source. So my guess is that you are not loading some file properly.

Comment: @Fede I'm loading bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-responsive.min.css, jquery-1.9.1.js and bootstrap-dropdown.js. Maybe should I use a lower jquery version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i'm loading:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I tried your code, loading a bootrasp I have in my machine and a the jquery from the site. and it works perfectly in FF, chrome and safari. I don't have a explorer to test it.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem but found that i was loading both

*bootstrap.min.js*

and

*bootstrap.dropdown.js*

this was causing a conflict in my code, you dont need to load both as the dropdown code is included in bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 3):

"min" versions cause problem some times (I face issues with .min files occasionally with ASP.NET MVC)

I had same issue, tried with bootstrap.js and it works fine!

Try same at your end.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and take care of `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working for me. Where did you find this solution?

Comment: Look at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1):

You need to load bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js before you load bootstrap-dropdown.js.
Bootstrap dropdown is a js plugin with a dependancy on the Bootstrap framework.

Your footer section would then look like this:

```
<footer>
  <p>© Company 2013</p>
</footer>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

You can customize your build of Bootstrap, then you don't have to separately include the bootstrap-dropdown.js—it will be loaded with Bootstrap.

Bootstrap custom download:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: though this was not the solution or even the problem i was addressing was different but i got another idea from this so  +1 mate...I voted you up...thanks

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use Django framework, after 4 hours of debugging

I just used bootstrap.js instead of bootstrap.min.js [screenshot of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlgWr.png)

After that, the issue has been resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).