# Why are dropdowns and burger menus in Bootstrap 5.0.1 not opening anywhere?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I've recently started building a WordPress template using Bootstrap (I downloaded Bootstrap and link it directly through my website files.) Everything works, except for elements that require JavaScript, such as dropdowns. However, I have properly enqueued bootstrap.bundle.min.js in my functions.php page.
I have also included Jquery, and I made sure the two are in the right order (Jquery being enqueued first.) But dropdowns and burger menus still will not open or work. They only display like so: [dropdown displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RI98.png) (when you click on it, nothing happens)

I tried moving things around, using different browsers, enqueueing other scripts like bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js (never together, always one at a time), and nothing makes dropdowns work on any device or any browser.

I tried every solution in this similar Stack Overflow question: [Twitter Bootstrap dropdown not working in any browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592158/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-any-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1)
. Still nothing.

The code I use for my dropdown is literally copy-pasted from the Bootstrap documentation (*I added the `<link>` and the `<script>` so it works in the example snippet. I use my functions.php page to enqueue scripts and stylesheets*):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will paste the code from my functions.php page below, in case it helps:

```html
<?php

function loadStylesheets(){

    wp_register_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 5, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('mainStyle',get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('mainStyle');

    wp_register_style('fontStyle',get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('fontStyle');

    wp_register_style('colorStyle',get_template_directory_uri() . '/customColors.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('colorStyle');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadStylesheets');


function includeJquery(){

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', '', 3, true);
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includeJquery');


function loadJS(){

    wp_register_script('bootstrapJS',get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', '', 5, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapJS');

    wp_register_script('mainScripts',get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/scripts.js', '', false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('mainScripts');


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadJS');
```

Guys, I made an entire Stack Overflow account just for this. I never post stuff because the answer is usually here, but I've searched far and wide to no avail. I'm desperate, and I've troubleshot for a whole day on this single issue.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have been using the docs for Bootstrap <v4.6.x. In v5.0 the dropdown-menu class is a list <ul> that uses <li> elements to wrap the dropdown links. Here it is using the sample from v5.0 docs:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it was a silly mistake like that hahaha
Thank you so much! It works perfectly now