# Bootstrap requires JQuery but Bootstrap dropdown only working if JQuery is loaded after Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

My problem is with these two rows' order:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>`

-Normally Bootstrap requires JQuery or I get the error:"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"

-If I use Bootstrap Dropdown then Dropdown is only working properly if I change the order of the rows. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/23985019/7947815 )

What should I do?

Comment: so what order works for you?

Comment: Dropdown is working fine if 1.Bootstrap 2. JQuery

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: by putting Bootstrap first, do you get an error from Bootstrap?

Comment: please show you script imports in HTML

Answer (score 0):

[**Version 4 Beta**](https://getbootstrap.com/), it's supposed to be in below order

1. JQuery js
2. Popper js
3. Bootstrap js

---

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Version 3.3.7**, you are supposed to have following order

[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/XzVLMV)

1. Jquery
2. Bootstrap

Comment: the OP is using Bootstrap 3.3.7